# Does the molecule LiF3 exist?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, lewis-structure

Can LiF3 exist? (1 lithium and 3 fluorines), and if so, what would the Lewis dot diagram look like?

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27920/why-is-nacl3-possible

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7800/can-fluorine-act-as-the-central-atom-in-interhalogen-compounds

Answer (score 6):

Lithium with an oxidation state of +3 would seem beyond the pale, but [all the halogens are known to form trihalide ions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/122036/17175). Thus in principle one could imagine a salt, $\ce{Li^+(F3^-)}$.

However, trihalide ions are generally not stable in salts except with a bulky, essentially nonpolarizing cation or at GPa-level pressures; [even caesium does not impart a perfectly symmetrical triiodide ion structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triiodide). Therefore, the proposed lithium trifluoride, with a small and relatively polarizing cation, would be expected to decompose to $\ce{LiF + F2}$.

Comment: Perhaps at high pressures the trifluoride could be a stable compound, however there are certain technical difficulties involved in such an investigation.

Comment: Agreed. I chose not to open that can of worms, partly because at least with caesium other (more fascinating) factors enter the picture. See [Zhu et al.](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep07875).

Comment: I wonder, if a Lewis adduct of LiF and F2 would be possible in gas phase. AuF5 is strong enough to make it, so maybe monomeric LiF also is...

Comment: @mithoron I would not bet on it, AuF5 is a uniquely strong Lewis acid. F2 coordination seems not to be reported with other Lewis acids such as SbF5 or BF3.